# Не убираются лишние поля с формы заказа в Wordpress

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

При попытке отключить лишние поля из формы оформления заказа ничего не происходит. Поля остаются на месте и при редактировании файла functions.php дочерней темы и при использовании плагинов по типу  Woocommerce Checkout manager. В плагине поля убираются/отключаются, но на странице заказа ничего не происходит.
Отключение всех иных плагинов то же не дало результатов.
Версия woocommerce - 8.4.0

Третью неделю голову ломаю.=(
Пример кода в дочерней теме:

```
function custom_my_fields($fields) {
    
    //$fields["billing"]["billing_last_name"]["required"] = false;   // Фамилия не обязательна
    //$fields["billing"]["billing_phone"]["required"] = true;        // Телефон обязателен

$fields["billing"]["billing_first_name"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_last_name"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_company"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_address_1"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_address_2"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_city"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_postcode"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_country"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_state"]["required"] = false;
//$fields["billing"]["billing_email"]["required"] = false;
$fields["billing"]["billing_phone"]["required"] = false;

$fields["shipping"]["shipping_first_name"]["required"] = false;
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_last_name"]["required"] = false;
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_company"]["required"] = false;
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_address_1"]["required"] = false;
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_address_2"]["required"] = false;
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_city"]["required"] = false;
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_postcode"]["required"] = false;
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_country"]["required"] = false;
$fields["shipping"]["shipping_state"]["required"] = false;

$fields["order"]["order_comments"]["required"] = false;
    return $fields;
 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
  
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);    // Поле имя
unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);     // Поле фамилия
unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);       // Поле компания
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);     // Поле адрес
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);     // Поле адрес 2
unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);          // Поле город
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);      // Поле индекс
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);       // Поле страна
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);         // Поле штат - область
unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);         // Поле телефон
unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);          // Поле комментарий к заказу
  //unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);         // Поле email адрес
  //unset($fields['account']['account_username']);      // Поле имя пользователя (логин)
  //unset($fields['account']['account_password']);      // Поле пароль (регистрация)
  //unset($fields['account']['account_password-2']);    // Поле повтор пароля (регистрация)

  unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);         // Поле компания
  unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);        // Поле индекс 
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Плагинами нормально всё настраивается. Любыми из оф каталога.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что плагины не работают так же, как и код.
сайт: https://pastryprof.ru/?page_id=28
Может ли это быть проблема настройки темы? Где и куда искать?

Comment: Переключитесь на стандартную тему и попробуйте это сделать на ней.

Comment: Пробовал. Даже пересносил сайт. На чистом сайте с темой stonefont (прямо по мануалу) с установленным woocommerce и Woocommerce Checkout manager - поля все равно не отключаются.

Comment: Ещё раз: плагины работают https://i.imgur.com/nkcjlm9.jpeg. В этом можно быстро убедится развернув сайт в песочнице. Если **у тебя** что-то не работает - ищи где поломал.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку про песочницу! Не знал, что такое существует.
Но даже в песочнице при установке с нуля, загрузки woocommerce  и checkout manager не удается убрать поля. В woocommerce  заполнил все поля, создал тестовый товар, установил значение в плагине checkout.
Может есть какая-то настройка специфическая?